MOSFET always turns on when connected with switch
I am having a simple circuit that basically needs to connect 2 points when a switch is closed. I can do this with switch directly but as the switch contacts might have significant resistance I wanted to use a P-Channel MOSFET DMG3415 to do it.
Here's the circuit I have used.

However I see that no matter the switch is closed or open the Pin A and Pin B are always connected and the MOSFET is always On. What could be the issue?

Whether or not this will work depends on the voltage relationships between +5V and pinA, and between GND and PinB.  If they are unconnected, it's all a bit undefined.

Note also that there's a body diode between Pin A and Pin B.  If Pin A is higher voltage than Pin B by more than a diode drop, the diode will always conduct.

@JohnD if i choose a FET ithout a diode between the terminals then would that work properly with this circuitry? But would any such FET even exist?

You can use back-to-back FETs for a bi-directional switch, but you still have to control the gate to source voltage correctly to switch on and off.  GaN FETs typically don't have a body diode, but again proper control of the gate voltage with respect to the terminal that becomes the source (based on polarity) is important.

@JohnD What if I just reverse Pins A and B? That would stop the conduction right?

@Hako If the voltage on pin B is higher than the voltage on pin A, it won't conduct.  You have to control the gate voltage with respect to the source (pin B) in order to turn the FET on and off.

If pin A is more positive than pin B, the FET will conduct regardless how you control it.
Basically for that circuit to work, pin B would need to be at 5V, so that there is either 5V or 0V at the gate, controlled by the pushbutton.
The A and B wires will also need to share same ground and supply than the button.
So the FET gate, button, ground and supply can not be isolated from whatever A and B are going to.
